# pchart zend framework error "The image Cannot be displayed because it contains errors"

Tags: php, image, zend-framework

Am using **pchart** to create charts for a **zend framework application**. My problem is that i cant get the application to display the chart as each time am getting the above named error. I have looked at the various solutions related to the problem but i its still not working. Is there anything that am missing here? Please refer to the code

{

```
    require 'pChart2.1.1/pChart2.1.1/class/pData.class.php'; 
    require 'pChart2.1.1/pChart2.1.1/class/pDraw.class.php';
    require 'pChart2.1.1/pChart2.1.1/class/pImage.class.php';
    require 'pChart2.1.1/pChart2.1.1/class/pPie.class.php';


   // action body
    $users = new Application_Model_DbTable_Users();
    $users = $users->listAll();

    $id=$this->_getParam('id');

    if($id)
    {
            $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender(true);
            $this->_helper->layout()->disableLayout();
            $response=$this->getResponse();
            $response->clearBody('top_menu');
            $response->clearAllHeaders();

    if ($id == 'pdf') {
                  }


        //request is a chart

        if($id=='chart')
        {
            ob_start();

            $departments=new Application_Model_DbTable_Departments();

            $departments=$departments->fetchAll();

            $departments->toArray();

            $department_id="";
            $department_name="";

            foreach ($departments as $departments) {
                $department_id[]=$departments['department_id'];
                $department_name[]=$departments['department_name'];



                /* pData object creation */
               $MyData = new pData();
                /* Data definition */
                $MyData->addPoints(array(20, 30, 25, 10), "Value");
                    /* Labels definition */
                $MyData->addPoints($department_name, "Legend");
                $MyData->setAbscissa("Legend");
                /* Create the pChart object */
                $myPicture = new pImage(500, 500, $MyData);
                /* Draw a gradient background */
                $myPicture->drawGradientArea(0, 0, 500, 500, 
                DIRECTION_HORIZONTAL, 
                array("StartR" => 220, "StartG" => 220, "StartB" => 220, 
                "EndR" => 180, "EndG" => 180, "EndB" => 180, "Alpha" => 100));
                /* Add a border to the picture */
                $myPicture->drawRectangle(0, 0, 400, 400, 
                array("R" => 0, "G" => 0, "B" => 0));
                /* Create the pPie object */
                $PieChart = new pPie($myPicture, $MyData);
                /* Enable shadow computing */
                $myPicture->setShadow(FALSE);
                /* Set the default font properties */
                $myPicture->setFontProperties(
                array(
                "FontName" => "pChart2.1.1/pChart2.1.1/fonts/Forgotte.ttf", 
                "FontSize" => 10, "R" => 80, "G" => 80, "B" => 80));
                /* Draw a splitted pie chart */
                $PieChart->draw3DPie(200, 150, 
                array("Radius" => 100, "DrawLabels" => TRUE, 
                "DataGapAngle" => 10, "DataGapRadius" => 6, "Border" => TRUE));
                /* Render the picture (choose the best way) */

                header ("Content-type: image/png" );
                $myPicture->Stroke("pie.png");

                exit;


            }


        }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is almost certainly something being output either before or after the image content. Easiest thing to do would be to temporarily comment out your `header("Content-type: image/png");` line and view the chart image in a browser. You'll see a load of binary data (the image) - look for anything before or after it that looks out of place (e.g. PHP error message, some HTML, possibly white space).

Comment: i have still not managed to clear, i checked my binary image and it seems okay,do you think the require statements could be the issue here?

Comment: It's possible, try removing the closing ?> at the end of each class you're requiring in (if they have one). That prevents any whitespace after it causing issues.

Answer (score 0):

After many days, i finally got the mistakes that i made first there  was an empty line in my bootstrap and an the end of my controller, i also placed my pchart in my public folder because it has the fonts and lastly i realized that i should set the response header at the top.

Thanks all !